# ignore all .git folders in .dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-build

I have a project that have a few git clones, every folder will have his .git and some folder has clones inside folders

So it's possible to ignore all .git folders?

I tested many rules as described in the docs, but I only managed to ignore on the top folder.

Answer (score 55):

It suffices to use the `**` pattern. For example:

> .dockerignore

```
**/.git
```

The relevant passage from [that page of the official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) is:

> ## .dockerignore file
>
> […]
>
> Matching is done using Go’s [filepath.Match](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath#Match) rules. A preprocessing step removes leading and trailing whitespace and eliminates `.` and `..` elements using Go’s [filepath.Clean](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Clean). Lines that are blank after preprocessing are ignored.
>
> Beyond Go’s filepath.Match rules, Docker also supports a special
>   wildcard string `**` that matches any number of directories (including
>   zero). For example, `**/*.go` will exclude all files that end with `.go`
>   that are found in all directories, including the root of the build
>   context.
>
> […]

## Working example

Here is a complete session with Docker CE under Debian GNU/Linux:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:13:52 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 03:42:13 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Consider the following working directory:

```
$ tree -a
.
├── a
│   ├── .git
│   │   └── c
│   └── go
│       └── 1
├── b
│   ├── c
│   │   ├── .git
│   │   │   └── c
│   │   └── go
│   │       └── 1
│   ├── .git
│   │   └── c
│   └── go
│       └── 1
├── Dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
├── .git
│   └── c
└── go
    └── 1
```

And the following source files:

```
$ cat .dockerignore
**/.git

$ cat Dockerfile
FROM debian

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD ls -Rhal
```

Then I get:

```
$ docker build -t test .
[…]

$ docker run --rm -it test 
.:
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:43 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 Feb 20 19:38 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Feb 20 19:40 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 a
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 b
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:40 go

./a:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 go

./a/go:
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 20 19:39 1

./b:
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 c
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 go

./b/c:
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 go

./b/c/go:
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 20 19:39 1

./b/go:
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:39 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 20 19:39 1

./go:
total 8.0K
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Feb 20 19:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb 20 19:40 1
```

Comment: I tried that, and it only removed on the top folder, the folder (fake name) 'extension/.git' was still there and the same for all subfolders.

Comment: @MateusSilva I'm puzzled to read that you were not able to make it work in your environment... I think this should work, and I edited my answer to include a complete session example of this feature...

Comment: Do you have other lines in your `.dockerignore`? (you didn't mention that in your question) Also, do you have **only one** `Dockerfile` and is your `Dockerfile` placed in the same folder as the top-level `.dockerignore`?

Comment: one dockerfile and dockerignore is in the same folder, i only created the dockerignore to ignore the git, so i was testing only this one line, i'm using macos mojave, and i will try to recreate and post here the exact process.

Comment: Is it **/*.git or **/.git it looks like the first is correct, but there’s a typo here?

Comment: @dacopenhagen nope, the `**` pattern is correct and documented in [this page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file): *Beyond Go’s filepath.Match rules, Docker also supports a special wildcard string `**` that matches any number of directories (including zero). For example, `**/*.go` will exclude all files that end with `.go` that are found in all directories, including the root of the build context.*

Comment: I apologize, that's not what I typed, I must have mistyped the formatting.
`**/.git` vs `**/*.git`

Comment: @dacopenhagen OK I see. But normally, `.git` is not a file extension: it is the [*default full name of the directory that gathers the contents of a non-bare Git repository*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_description).